# iPhone: Is it possible outside of jail breaking an iPhone device to access cache.db?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, filesystem

Is it possible outside of jail breaking an iPhone to access the cache.db from iOS 8.3 or above? I am currently using iMazing and I seem to not be able to find the cache.db file.

I found this source

> https://www.macrumors.com/2015/04/13/ios-8-3-ifunbox-itools-sandbox-app-access/

that seems to confirm this.

However, I want to be 100% sure about this.

Edit: I can access it through simulator, but not on actual device properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with iFunbox and iExplorer to view root files, but neither helps you edit them. It offers a sand-boxed version of iOS filesystem. You won’t be able to make any hard changes on your device without a proper jailbreak.

By default, the iOS is jailed. And jailbreaking removes the jailed status and allow us the full view of iOS filesystem with applications like iFunBox.

Here is iExplorer if you want to give it a try.

https://macroplant.com/iexplorer

Comment: I don't want to make changes, but just view the cache.db. It seems with iExplorer I can't view the cache.db at all.

Comment: Ok, then give iFunBox a try. I read on Macworld that iExplorer lets you see it (as in the filename) but not open it or view it.